# Unexpectedly found nill while trying to unwrap label from a custom Collection View Cell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I've created a custom Collection View Cell class which is as simple as this:

```swift
import UIKit

class AchievementCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var achieveLabel: UILabel!
}
```

Outlets are connected to corresponding items in prototype cell. Apparently when I try to assign text and an image to this outlets I get an error `Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value`

Here is the code I use:

```swift
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! AchievementCollectionViewCell
        // Configure the cell
        let achievement = achievementList[indexPath.row]
        cell.achieveLabel.text = achievement.name

        return cell
}
```

Debugger shows that both imageView and achieveLabel are nill when I reference them in the code above. How can I fix it?

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your question.

Comment: You have not given enough info. My guess is that you have registered the cell class with the collection view in your viewDidLoad. If so delete that.

Comment: @matt You are right! It was the problem! Thank you very much!

Comment: Ok gave that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably saying `self.collectionView?.register` for your cell type somewhere. If so, delete that line. You must not register the cell if you are getting it from the storyboard.